# Start new thread on buttonclick

Tags: android, button, action

I want my button to start up a new thread and destroy the one on which the button is located, upon clicking it, how do i do this?

```
package inno.games;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Introscreen extends Activity {


Button proceed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);


proceed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bProceed);



}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> destroy the [thread] on which the button is located

Although your wording is not exactly clear, there is only one UI thread which is the main thread. The button being part of the UI "is located" (more or less) on the UI thread. You can't destroy that thread and replace it.

If there's something specific that you're looking to achieve by this, you should post that along with specific requirements.

**Update:**

If you just want to create a new thread on click then technically this does it:

```
proceed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void OnClick(View v) {
        new Thread();
    }
});
```

but that doesn't exactly do anything useful. Also note that creating a new thread does not "get the CPU usage to a minimum". Creating a new thread creates **more** work for the CPU to do. However, you might be able to move some work from the UI thread to a background thread which will make the user experience smoother. If that's your goal, you should probably read this [document entitled Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, it was just to get the CPU usage to a minimum tbh. But if it isn't possible, is there any chance you might know the answer to the most essential question (creating a thread on click)?

Comment: Updated to address your comment.

Comment: Might be a bit easier if i just explain the whole point :)
The current GUI (thread) is consisting of an editview and a button. I've already made the .XML file for the GUI i want to appear when clicking on the button. (I also want the button to transfer the contents of the editview to the next GUI, but that i'll figure out myself :)) Btw... I'm struggling very hard getting it to override the OnClick.. i can't find it when going to source and trying to implement methods.

Comment: Make sure you imported `View.OnClickListener` and not `Dialog.OnClickListener`. They're both called `OnClickListener` but have different method signatures for handling their respective click events. It sounds like you might need some help with fundamentals. Take a read through [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html), you might find it helpful. You don't need to create a new thread, just a new Activity.