# Android Thread Launched from Button

Tags: android, multithreading, button

I have been struggling to get a thread to launch and run in the background of my app.
My question is, How do I create a thread and launch it from a button? I'm sorry for creating this question but I have spent at least 5 hours with no progress at all.

Comment: You should post some of your code to show what you have already tried

Comment: duplicate question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404456/start-new-thread-on-buttonclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_button_id.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                startThread();                          
            }
        });

create method 

public void startThread()
{
    Thread backgroundthread =new Thread( new Runnable() 
        {

            public void run()
            {

//Write your code that should be run on thread.Dont render UI here.
//render UI after thread in response handler like this...
    responceHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);


}});backgroundthread.start();
}

private Handler responceHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

if(msg.what==0)
{
//Handle your UI here 
}
}};
```